# Trying to find number of 1s groups in a given 2-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, c

I have written a code with recursive technique, but the program shows segmentation fault error. Did I Make any algorithm fault or its just a mistake in my code??

**QUESTION:**

There are R*C cells in a matrix where R is the number of rows and C is the number of cells in each row. Each cell may or may not have a fruit in it. The presence of a fruit is indicated by 1 and the absence of a fruit in a cell is indicated by 0. The fruits can be of different types and all the fruits belonging to the same type are arranged in adjacent cells (there are eight adjacent cells: top-left, top, top-right, left, right, bottom-left, bottom, bottom-right). The program must print the number of groups of fruits in the matrix.

**Boundary Condition(s):**
2 <= R, C <= 50

```
Input:
3 5
1 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 1
 
Output:
2
 
Explanation:
The first group is indicated by the letter F, 
F 0 0 0 1
0 F 0 1 1
F 0 0 0 1
The second group is indicated by the letter S,
1 0 0 0 S
0 1 0 S S
1 0 0 0 S

Input:
5 6
1 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 1 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 1 1
 
Output:
5
```

A **1** must be at least adjacent of one **1** of the group to be considered as a member of the group.

My solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int R, C, rtnval = 1;

int checkBoundary(int i, int j)
{
    return (i>-1 && j>-1 && i<R && j<C);
}

void checkGroup(int arr[R][C],int i, int j)
{
    if(arr[i][j]==1)
    {
        arr[i][j] = 0;
        //top
        if((checkBoundary(i-1,j)!=0) && arr[i-1][j]==1)
        {
            checkGroup(arr,i-1,j);
            //return;
        }
        //top-left
        if((checkBoundary(i-1,j-1)!=0) && arr[i-1][j-1]==1)
        {
            //arr[i-1
            checkGroup(arr,i-1,j-1);
            //return;
        }
        //top-right
        if((checkBoundary(i-1,j+1)!=0) && arr[i-1][j+1]==1)
        {
            //arr[i-1
            checkGroup(arr,i-1,j+1);
            //return;
        }
        //bottom
        if((checkBoundary(i+1,j)!=0) && arr[i+1][j]==1)
        {
            //arr[i+1
            checkGroup(arr,i+1,j);
            //return;
        }
        //bottom-left
        if((checkBoundary(i+1,j-1)!=0) && arr[i+1][j-1]==1)
        {
            checkGroup(arr,i+1,j-1);
        }
        //bottom-right
        if((checkBoundary(i+1,j+1)!=0) && arr[i+1][j+1]==1)
        {
            checkGroup(arr,i+1,j+1);
        }
        //left
        if((checkBoundary(i,j-1)!=0) && arr[i][j-1]==1)
        {
            checkGroup(arr,i,j-1);
        }
        //right
        if((checkBoundary(i,j+1)!=0) && arr[i][j+1]==1)
        {
            checkGroup(arr,i,j+1);
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    scanf("%d%d",&R,&C);
    int arr[R][C];
    for(int i=0;i<R;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<C;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int group = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<R;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<C;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i][j]==1)
            {
                checkGroup(arr,i,j);
                group++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d",group);
}
```

I have tried to follow all the leads to find any 1's and make them 0 so that they cant be mistook for other adjacent **1**s.

Comment: Can you please tell me more? I couldn't get you

Comment: I just wanted to ensure every move should be inside the boundary

Comment: Is there any way to make this code less if's and what is your suggestion for the I, j are both 0 thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, you need to verify that `checkBoundary(i, j)` returns true before checking if `arr[i][j] == 1` (and before attempting to access `arr` in general).

The same goes for each one of your internal 'if' statements, for example:

```
if(arr[i-1][j]==1 && (checkBoundary(i-1,j)!=0))
```

The `checkBoundary` call must be executed **before** accessing `arr`, not after.

Comment: Thanks I forgot that one, but still the problem is not solved.

Comment: @MohdGaming: You do realize that you need to verify that before **every** attempt to access `arr`, right? You have a bunch of those attempts inside the top-level 'if' statement. In each one of them, you attempt to access `arr` before you call `checkBoundary`, instead of after.

Comment: Yeah you are right Let me edit the code now for you to check. But now I have made a little change like, instead of returning values to get a group i just converted the one's which are adjacent to zero and incremented value of ```group``` every time i find a **1**.

Comment: Thanks bro that worked very well :)